# .htaccess - multi-language RewriteRule according to word translation and Env Variables

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to **translate a list of words** (blogs, news...) **from english to a detected language** and match the translation with various url structure and `RewriteRules`.

the url:

```
http://localhost/es/noticias
```

First the translation according to the detected language:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(es)\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/(es)/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=LANG:%1,E=NEWS:noticias,E=BLOGS:blogs]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(en)\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/(en)/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=LANG:%1,E=NEWS:news,E=BLOGS:blogs]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(fr)\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/(fr)/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=LANG:%1,E=NEWS:nouvelles,E=BLOGS:blogosphere]
```

One of the `RewriteRule` I try to create:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+/)?(blogs|noticias)  index.php?vd=%{ENV:LANG}/$1&m=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
.
.
.
```

How to **match the value of the translated env variables** (blogs,news...) with the requested uri via .htaccess?

**EDIT 1 - example of urls and rules**

```
#media index (ex: http://localhost/es/noticias)

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+/)?(videos|blogs|noticias|tiendas|enciclopedia|productos)  index.php?vd=%{ENV:LANG}/$1&m=$2&p=1 [NC,QSA,L]

#media service (ex: http://localhost/es/noticias/service1/)

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+/)?(videos|blogs|noticias|tiendas|enciclopedia|productos)/((?!recuweb).+)/$ index.php?vd=%{ENV:LANG}/$1&m=$2&sp=$3 [NC,L]

#media service categories (ex: http://localhost/es/noticias/service1/cat1/)

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+/)?(videos|blogs|noticias|tiendas|enciclopedia|productos)/((?!recuweb)[^\/-]+)/([^\/]+)/$ index.php?vd=%{ENV:LANG}/$1&m=$2&sp=$3&sc=$4 [NC,L]

#media year (ex: http://localhost/es/noticias/2014)

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+/)?(blogs|noticias)/([1-2][0-9]{3})$ index.php?vd=%{ENV:LANG}/$1&m=$2&yr=$3 [NC,L]

#media year search (ex: http://localhost/es/noticias/2014/search-terms)

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+/)?(blogs|noticias)/([1-2][0-9]{3})/([^\/]+)$ index.php?vd=%{ENV:LANG}/$1&m=$2&yr=$3&q=$4 [NC,L]

#media year domain (ex: http://localhost/es/noticias/es.newspaper.com)

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+/)?(videos|blogs|noticias)/(www\.)?((?!www\.)[^/.]+\.)?((?!www\.)[^/.]+\.)?([^/.]+\.[^/.]+)/([1-2][0-9]{3})?$ index.php?vd=%{ENV:LANG}/$1&m=$2&sc=$3$4$5$6&yr=$7 [NC,L]

#media search (ex: http://localhost/es/noticias/search-terms)

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+/)?(videos|blogs|noticias|tiendas|enciclopedia|productos)/([^\/]+)/?(rss)?$ index.php?vd=%{ENV:LANG}/$1&m=$2&q=$3&f=$4 [NC,L]

#media service search (ex: http://localhost/es/noticias/service1/search-terms)

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+/)?(videos|blogs|noticias|tiendas|enciclopedia|productos)/((?!recuweb)[^\/-]+)/([^\/]+)/?(2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10)?/?(rss)?$ index.php?vd=%{ENV:LANG}/$1&m=$2&sp=$3&q=$4&p=$5&f=$6 [NC,L]

#media service category search (ex: http://localhost/es/noticias/service1/cat1/search-terms)

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+/)?(videos|blogs|noticias|tiendas|enciclopedia|productos)/((?!recuweb)[^\/-]+)/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/?(2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10)?/?(rss)?$ index.php?vd=%{ENV:LANG}/$1&m=$2&sp=$3&sc=$4&q=$5&p=$6&f=$7 [NC,L]
```

Comment: "*How to match the value of the stored Variables with the requested uri via .htaccess?*" Do you mean matching the `$1` with what's in the `%{ENV:LANG}` variable?

Comment: Sorry, not the language the list of words (blogs, news...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `backrefencing` in a `rewrite condition` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGS}:%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^:]+):^/[^/]+/\1
```

Take note of `\1` which is back reference for env variable BLOGS that is being used to match `REQUEST_URI`.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to check all the translation in once using OR stratement?

Comment: Yes definitely it can be done in one single rule with `[OR]` clauses.

Comment: Sorry Anubhava, could you please provide me with a full answer including all the RewriteCond with the RewriteRule so I can check the suitability locally.

Comment: sure I can provide but I just couldn't understand all the requirements completely that's why I didn't so far. If you can just clarify the URIs you want to match and their expected rewrites etc in your question I will test it out locally and provide you complete answer.

Comment: Ok. It takes a moment.

Comment: Initially I was about to use multiple translated htaccess and directories but it would save me time if apache could translate dynamically using the same file

Comment: I have read your examples several times but couldn't establish your concrete requirements out of it. For ex. no where you're using LANG env variable. I just wanted to know how are you planning to derive logic based on those env variables and how do you want to use them in your rules.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44740/discussion-between-rafasashi-and-anubhava)